# Can I use Tkinter to create a Tcl interactive shell?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, ctypes

I am currently using ctypes in Python 3 to make a Tcl application that wraps a library written in Python.

```
from ctypes import *
import sys

tcl = cdll.LoadLibrary("libtcl.so")

TCL_OK = 0
TCL_ERROR = 1

def say_hello(cdata: c_void_p, interp: c_void_p, argc: c_int, argv: POINTER(c_char_p)) -> int:
    "This function wraps some functionality that is written in Python"
    print("hello, world")
    return TCL_OK

# useful type definitions
Tcl_AppInitProc = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_void_p)
Tcl_CmdProc = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int, POINTER(c_char_p))
Tcl_CmdDeleteProc = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int)

def app_init(interp: c_void_p) -> int:
    # initialize the interpreter
    tcl.Tcl_Init.restype = c_int
    tcl.Tcl_Init.argtypes = [c_void_p]
    if tcl.Tcl_Init(interp) == TCL_ERROR:
        return TCL_ERROR

    # create custom commands
    tcl.Tcl_CreateCommand.restype = c_void_p
    tcl.Tcl_CreateCommand.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p, Tcl_CmdProc, c_int, Tcl_CmdDeleteProc]
    tcl.Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, b"say_hello", Tcl_CmdProc(say_hello), 0, Tcl_CmdDeleteProc(0))

    return TCL_OK

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialize argv
    Argv = c_char_p * (1 + len(sys.argv))
    argv = Argv(*(bytes(arg, "utf-8") for arg in sys.argv), 0)

    # summon the chief interpreter
    tcl.Tcl_Main.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(c_char_p), Tcl_AppInitProc]
    tcl.Tcl_Main(len(sys.argv), argv, Tcl_AppInitProc(app_init))
```

From the command line, this works like a Tcl interpreter with extra commands, which is just what I want. It parses `sys.argv` and works both as an interactive shell and to run Tcl scripts.

```
bash$ python3 hello.py
% say_hello
hello, world
% ls 
foo.tcl  hello.py
% exit
bash$ cat foo.tcl
say_hello
bash$ python3 hello.py foo.tcl
hello, world
bash$
```

However, I know that Python comes with a Tcl interpreter already in the tkinter module. I'd like to use that, instead, because it already has a nice Python-wrapped API and could save me some futzing about with ctypes.

I can create an interpreter and add commands easily enough.

```
from tkinter import *

def say_hello():
    print("hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tcl = Tcl()
    tcl.createcommand("say_hello", say_hello)
    tcl.eval("say_hello")
```

But I can't find any way to call `Tcl_Init` or `Tcl_Main`, and without those I can't run it interactively. While I don't care that much about the command line parser, it would be a lot of work to try to replicate the Tcl interactive shell in Python with all its features, like running external programs as if they were Tcl commands (such as `ls` in the above example). If that's my only option, I'll just stick with using ctypes.

Is there any way, even a hacky or unsupported one, to run the Tcl interpreter that comes with Tkinter as an interactive shell?

Comment: `Tcl` is the same as `Tk`. `tkinter` imports `_tkinter` which is the [`_tkinter.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c) part, look there about your missing functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REPL implemented in `Tcl_Main()` is really very simple minded; you can do a (slightly cut down) version of it in a few lines of Tcl:

```
set cmd ""
set prompt "% "
while true {
    # Prompt for input
    puts -nonewline $prompt
    flush stdout
    if {[gets stdin line] < 0} break

    # Handle multiline commands
    append cmd $line "\n"
    if {![info complete $cmd]} {
        set prompt ""
        continue
    }
    set prompt "% "

    # Evaluate the command and print error/non-empty results
    if {[catch $cmd msg]} {
        puts stderr "Error: $msg"
    } elseif {$msg ne ""} {
        puts $msg
    }
    set cmd ""
}
```

All you need to do is run that inside the Tcl interpreter inside the Python code. You could also reimplement most of the REPL in Python; the only pieces you really need Tcl for then will be `info complete $cmd` (testing if a complete command is in the input buffer) and `catch $cmd msg` (evaluating the input buffer in the Tcl interpreter and trapping results & errors).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `info complete`. I'll look into this more

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted, because it looks like what I'm going to do, but I'd still be interested to find out about other approaches!